# Haystack: Highlight only one field

Tags: django, elasticsearch, highlight, django-haystack

I'm using **Haystack 2.3.0**, and I have a search index like:

```
class MyModelIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='name', boost=1.250)
    short_description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='short_description', null=True, boost=1.125)
    description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description', null=True, boost=1.125)
    detail_description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='detail_description', null=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return MyModel
```

I'd like to highlight only the field **`detail_description`**. I've read in the [official documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/highlighting.html#highlighter) this example:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content='foo').highlight()
result = sqs[0]
result.highlighted['text'][0]
```

But when I try to do that I don't get the same result. In the example above, `result.highlighted` seems to be a **dictionary** where you can access the highlight of **each field:**

```
result.highlighted['text'][0]
```

But in my example, when I do the same, `result.highlighted` is not a dictionary, it is a list, and only return the highlight of the `text` field.

- How could I set the highlight to a concrete field ?

Answer (score 3):

> If the number_of_fragments value is set to 0 then no fragments are
>   produced, instead the whole content of the field is returned, and of
>   course it is highlighted. This can be very handy if short texts (like
>   document title or address) need to be highlighted but no fragmentation
>   is required. Note that fragment_size is ignored in this case.

From

LINK - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html

You need to see how to change this parameter in haystack.

Comment: So, `number_of_fragments` seems to be `0` and because of that ElasticSearch is returning only 1 field ? Thanks for pointing me in the good direction, I'm going to dive in the Haystack documentation

Comment: Sure , i am guessing it should be there in highlight() function call

Comment: The Haystack documentation says the highlight function call doesn't receive any argument ! But thanks for helping me to understand why this is happening !

Answer (score 0):

My temporary solution right now is to do a for loop and add the highlight manually to the field, like this:

```
for result in sqs:
    highlight = Highlighter(my_query)  # my_query has the word(s) of the query
    result.detail_description = highlight.highlight(result.detail_description)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late here, but if you want to pass extra params to highlight, you need to pass a dict of whatever params elasticsearch would want for the highlight function, like so:

```
# Solr example since I'm not familiar with ES
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content='foo').highlight(**{'hl.fl': 'short_description')
```